# Shouldn't we have One Suggestion box along with answer boxes

Tags: feature-request

We have comment section under question and answers to discuss, ask more information and even sometime suggest possible solution in short but future users when search for problems, check posts and answers on stackoverflow, I bet 90% of them won't bother to read the comments and I noticed during discussions on questions, very experienced and reputable users post very valuable information and suggestions which no use because comments mostly get ignored. So shouldn't there be a suggestion box where suggestion or valueable information and experience which users share during discussion can store and future users can take benefits from it.

Comment: You do realize this is a Q&A (and comments) site, right?

Comment: yes and i asked a question sorry i forget to put question mark at the end

Comment: ... that wasn't my point, but ok.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question, the point and reason i asked the question is because i felt if the valuable information can be preserved it help future users, but if you think and believe its irrelevant i delete the question and go with the flow :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to respond to questions: comments and answers. Users who post debugging hints and sometimes even possible answer in comments, such as me, can't be bothered at the moment to write a full answer.

For me, doing so can have various reasons:

- OP not responding to comments or seeming to be at a whole other experience or language level (so the discussion will drag on in comments under the answer, because they won't understand the comment, or I'll have to write an extremely long answer explaining the basics).
- The problem description being vague altogether (it could be a duplicate of plenty other questions) are the main causes to post a comment instead of an answer.
- The problem seems clear, but it's so trivial that I don't feel like scoring easy points.
- I simply don't have time to type an answer.

That being said, if OP can't be bothered to reply to those comments (which happens more often than you think) or someone else won't use the information in them to write a full fledged answer, then it's their loss.

We don't need a third way to sling information OP's way. We have enough users using answers as suggestion box already, read [What should a minimal answer contain?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain).