# "I'm not sure I understand your question" and other memes

Tags: discussion

SO is most valuable and I applaud it even though there are 2 response memes that burn my grits...  I don't know what can be done about them other than to raise awareness, but I'd sure like to see editors mark them with a special category and that to carry a penalty.

1 "I'm not sure I understand your question"...  Then please don't answer it.  Or just state one's assumptions for the optimal case inferred and then take one's best shot at a cogent answer.  I interpret this opening statement as haughty pedantry.

2 "Please don't do that".  (Since when did engineers become so moralistic and censurious?  It used to be that engineers were keen to swap techniques and become familiar with something new to them, (even if ultimately they personally rejected its adoption.)  In every case I think I have seen of this, the OP had a use case the responder had not been able to imagine.

Q. are these memes helpful in any way or just obstructive?  what can be done about them?

Comment: can't see how either is a "meme". the first one can be taken as feedback that your question is unclear though given the poster of the comment should really indicate how it's unclear to help the asker improve. depending on the context the second one can be an indication when you're trying something that's not best practices, eg. not sanitizing/validating user input

Comment: Example situation: you attempt to stick your fingers inside a socket. People tell you _not to do that_. You answer: "Since when did engineers become so moralistic and censorious?"

Comment: I'd suggest these are memes because you see them often enough that there is some plausible likelihood that they're being copied from example.

The questions might be fine on the surface if one didn't suspect that there is an opening gambit to establish a sense of authority and superiority.

The psychology of programmers in teams doesn't get much attention but I'd suggest it's the King Kong of productivity gain and loss.

Comment: Someone commenting that they don't understand the question probably means the question needs to be re-worded, because it's likely that *others* will also not understand the question. Taking one's best shot at the ambiguous question is a terrible idea. You'll just end up with shotgunned answers, most of which have nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: You would like to penalize something that seems fine on the surface but you "suspect that there is an opening gambit to establish a sense of authority and superiority"? That seems like a very subjective reason to apply a penalty.

Comment: If the opening statement doesn't add anything to the answer, it's fluff and can be edited out. If it adds to the answer (in case 1, leads into a statement of assumptions that the answer is based off of or points out specifics that could be improved in the question, or case 2, makes good and secure suggestions for alternatives), then assume that the poster is benevolent because they have made a net positive contribution to the community. If the answer as a whole is bad, downvote or flag as you feel is appropriate and move on.

Comment: Not sure this is a productive discussion: it seems somewhat natural to say you're unsure whether you understood the question right, and still answer. You *may* be giving the right answer... as KernelPanic says, you can always edit it out. Re the second thing, the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is a real thing; in the vast majority of cases, "don't do that" is actually the correct response! I learned a lot of things here on SO just from people who told me "don't do that because...". Why would we take that away?

Comment: The first one is a polite nudge for you to clarify your question lest it be closed. The second one is when you have an XY problem. You want to do X and X is somewhat possible if you ignore convention and common sense, but you really ought to do Y instead so people tell you that.

Comment: Perhaps an example to illustrate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12234064/3554017

The claim that this has been a convention since C programming days is particularly egregious.

+1 to everyone who is using imagination to try to think of better ways to couch the same sentiments in a way that is actually informative and productive.

Comment: @koan911: Yeah, "Please don't do that" for things that are a matter of personal preference does seem egregious. But I'm not sure that's any more common than folks saying "Please don't do that" for things people *really* shouldn't be doing, like building SQL statements with plain string concatenation.

Comment: I agree that's an example where "don't do that" is inappropriate and should be a comment, but I'm not convinced that's the norm, nor that the answer existing is a huge problem even there. It's one of several answers; in SO's point-based society, you'll *always* find someone willing to answer the literal question. Also, it's likely to get downvoted. As said, very often "don't do that" is exactly what the asker needs and we should be careful not to discourage it too much. In my experience we already police those kinds of answers way too much in favour of answering every question literally.

Comment: Unfortunately, being honest, eg 'your question makes no sense at all' is often taken as offensive.  I wish posters would just take what comes. (unless actually and clearly abusive), without continually moaning about what they get as FREE help. If they want yes-men, they can pay them.   The skilled and experienced engineers who give free time/effort on SO should feel free to speak up about bad practices etc. and continual sniping at their reasonable responses on meta is really annoying.

Comment: In general though this seems like another XY problem.... You seem to think 'stack is coders helping coders'. Close.... But not quite. Stack is 'building a long lasting repo of high quality, low noise content'. To do that, we have to provide best practices, not simply solve the exact question you ask. How would you feel if, Googling your next issue, you find code on SO that introduces a fatal security flaw in your system, because no one told the OP'don't do that'....

Comment: *Or just state one's assumptions for the optimal case inferred and then take one's best shot at a cogent answer.* - Sounds like a good way to get an answer ban and/or trap the OP with a question that might not be salvageable.

Comment: @ForceBru More often than not as far as UX.SE and SO are concerned, it seems that the scenario is "I've been instructed to insert my fingers into a socket by my manager, how best can I do it?" (or, "how can I improve the user experience of inserting fingers in sockets"), to which people still complain. Either that or it's clarified later by the OP. It wastes a lot of time, and I've seen lots of text explaining why someone shouldn't do something where it generally won't make a difference. It creates a culture of starting each question with "I know I shouldn't, but...", which is useless.

Comment: 'opening gambit to establish a sense of authority and superiority' what?  There is no gambit because nothing is being sacrificed.  The act of asking for help on SO already implies that devs with more skill and experience will answer, so probable 'authority and superiority' in that area is a given.  Your question and comment makes no sense at all, (or would you prefer a more crawling, subservient, politically and socially 'correct' reply?).  ERROR #666: pseudo social/political claptrap detected in comment 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This post is mostly rambling but since it's on-topic, I figured I'd post it for others to read. I don't go into a lot of depth in most of my points, but I ramble just enough that you can probably follow my train of thought on some of them.

---

Sometimes I wonder if programmers become picky over the slightest things after having worked with code that trips up on the slightest typos for so long, or if the characteristic of pedantry lends itself to helping someone become a programmer. Either way, there is a reason people on Stack Overflow get picky, and it can feel unnecessary sometimes but I assure you, it's a good thing in many situations. I'm probably biased, of course, but I hope people can help us help them through cooperation. It's give and take from both sides.

There's nothing wrong with stating assumptions when answering a question — personally, I wish *more people did that* instead of just staying silent about their assumptions — but besides running the risk of making the wrong assumptions altogether (thereby wasting everybody's time), if you find yourself having to make *too* many assumptions then the problem lies with the question being either unclear or too broad, not with your answer. We want questions to be reasonably scoped, and clear, so

1. answerers know what they're dealing with and can answer definitively instead of throwing mud at the wall and seeing what sticks, and
2. visitors looking for answers can be sure that the answers are exactly what they're looking for.

If I don't "understand" a question simply because I don't know the language or the library in question, I ignore it. Because chances are that, as a matter of fact, I *do* understand the question — I simply don't have the knowledge to answer it.

But If I don't understand a question because it's vague, or worse, incoherent, chances are that not many people are going to understand it either. When somebody leaves a comment saying they don't understand, there's a reasonable chance they are speaking not just for themselves but for a broader group of people who would otherwise be the target audience of your question. (That's not to say there won't be those who stick their noses into questions they have no business answering, like somebody who has never seen a line of C++ code trying to answer a [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) question, but those are relatively uncommon.)

Unfortunately, in my experience I've also found that some well-written questions can be perceived as unclear or otherwise hard to understand simply because a large portion of the userbase doesn't speak English natively. Questions that are obvious and straightforward to a native speaker might well be a load of jargon to a non-native speaker. I really don't want to have to dumb down my posts, but I think there is an art to writing something that is comprehensive, fluent, yet easy to understand for a wide audience.

As for "Please don't do that", you won't believe how often we get questions about folks doing things they really shouldn't be doing. Yes, there are situations where the asker has a legitimate and sometimes even common use case no one has thought of (e.g. ["parsing" HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) — check out the next highest-scoring answer *after* the accepted one for what I'd consider a much more sensible response to the original question that's ironically not actually an answer; heck, [even I have been guilty of being wrong on this count at least once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-inline-style-attribute/8426901#comment42681112_8426901)), but there *are* situations where, seriously, no one in their right mind should be doing whatever it is they are doing (e.g. building an SQL statement by concatenating strings directly), and there are less egregious situations where the approach is not unreasonable but simply suboptimal. I think this is largely a case-by-case thing.

Comment: As to the last paragraph, that's known as the XY problem. You think you need to do X because of inexperience, and you may even be able to if you accept enough negative consequences, but the _real_ correct answer will recommend you to do Y instead, because Y is cleaner and easier for your purpose.

Comment: @Magisch: And that's how you know I was just rambling - I couldn't remember what it was called.

Answer (score 13):

> 1 "I'm not sure I understand your question"... Then please don't answer it. Or just state one's assumptions for the optimal case inferred and then take one's best shot at a cogent answer. I interpret this opening statement as haughty pedantry.

Honestly, this is a close reason - **Unclear What You're Asking** - and the comment can be interpreted not as passive-aggressive, but as a way to let you know that an onlooker doesn't really get what you're asking about here.  Don't take offense to it; **clarify your question!**

Asking them to answer an unclear question leaves everyone dissatisfied.  You get an incomplete answer, and the answerer provides faulty, incomplete, or misleading advice.  It's a lose-lose for everyone unless the question is clear.

> 2 "Please don't do that". (Since when did engineers become so moralistic and censurious? It used to be that engineers were keen to swap techniques and become familiar with something new to them, (even if ultimately they personally rejected its adoption.) In every case I think I have seen of this, the OP had a use case the responder had not been able to imagine.

There are times in which it makes sense to stop you from using string concatenation in your SQL string.  It's important for you to discern advice from criticism, and "please don't do that" can definitely fall under advice.

Comment: Also: future visitors won't know if they have the same problem if the question is unclear. We *care* about clarity of questions because that makes it useful long term.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you don't know the person who posts a comment or answers a question and what they mean by such a remark. Whenever you encounter a suboptimal remark, you'll have to go and investigate whether it is actually worth investigating.

Someone saying *"I don't understand this question"* can mean either of these two things:

- they don't have enough experience to know what you're talking about (or are having a bad day, or missed a crucial sentence in your question, or they misinterpreted a piece of code, etc),
- they actually know what they're doing, and you have an experienced member of the community trying to help you, but **you** don't have enough experience to clearly explain what you mean (or you are having a bad day, or you forgot to write a crucial sentence in your question, or you posted a irrelevant piece of code, etc).

This has **nothing** to do with elitism, group think, pedantism, and so on. It means the commenter (in the optimal case) is helping the site become a better place, and helping you become a better programmer.

Your suggestion seems to be:

> Just hurl whatever you can think of at the asker; they will figure out if it is relevant to them. Don't ask them to clarify; don't tell them not to do certain things.

That is **not** how this site works. A question must be clear enough to get a definitive answer, so any later visitor of the question can read it, evaluate whether it applies to them, and then continue reading the answers, which again, [should contain an explanation of the assumptions and premises under which it was written, what problem was extracted from the question and how the suggested fix would mitigate that problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811).

If you don't like all of that "noise", if you want to dig through a lot of irrelevant answers that just guess at what the asker meant, I would like to suggest you to try a different place where that behavior is commonplace, for example the Microsoft forums.

Comment: If the OP etc. is annoyed by apparent pedantry, they should not be on SO or in this business at all.  Compilers, linkers and processors do care excessively about rules.  They don't care about intent or plan. There is no 'touchy-feely' except to burn fingers.  If the code is wrong by one or two bits,, the chances are that the result will be completely disastrous.  It's therefore not surprising that software engineers tend to approach SO  questions in a similar manner.  If they don't like the heat in software development, they should be in the kitchen, (slinging burgers at KFC:).

Comment: @ThingyWotsit,  This is it right there: "engineers are exact about compilers and exact about English.  Good engineers are as precise as computers."  This is the meme.

Communication is about sharing information and that presupposes that both parties have some common basis of supporting knowledge (English and the subject domain).  And we don't and never do.  Bridging that is the challenge, especially on SO which aspires to be programmers helping other programmers.

Comment: @koan "meme" - you keep using that word, but I don't think you know what it means. What point are you trying to make? That we should be more friendly to people who don't know how to ask an understandable question?

Comment: @CodeCaster.  Thank you, sir.  A meme is an infectious idea that has the ability to replicate itself from mind to mind by as little as mere contact, especially when minds are unguarded by any kind of profound thought.  I'm not at all irritated but wishing for more effective (and less showy) communication.  I wanted to +1 you above for dissing Microsoft!  :)  See how the next responder, ThingyWotsit comes in and reprises your theme and takes MS down several notches to KFC?  Cont.

Comment: What I suggest is trivial:
1. issues X Y and Z are ambiguous (could be This or That)
2. I will assume in each case the following:....
3. Now I attempt to answer your question like this:....
4. please now clarify your question accordingly, esp if this is not the answer.  Or just do 1 and wait for clarification.  Or back off and wait for someone who *does* understand the OP.

same thing goes for, "don't do that".  Instead "If you do that, the following negatives are likely to accrue; therefore, I suggest....".