# Is it okay if I give an upvote to all the answers of my question?

Tags: discussion, voting

I asked a question on Stack Overflow and I found that all the answers are good, and I learned from all of them. Is it okay to give an upvote to every answer? Or is that bad for some reason?

Comment: If the answers are good, then yes, by all means, up-vote them all. You vote based on your perception of answer quality.

Comment: Please vote on the quality of each answer, separately. Do not try to add any other parameter to the vote: it should only represent the quality of the answer you're voting on. If they're all good, upvote all. If only some are good, only upvote those. If none are good, don't upvote. Simple! :)

Comment: In particular, try to avoid to upvote a post *just because they answered*. Your gut reaction may be to upvote everything and everyone, but as said, the votes on Stack Overflow are used to determine "helpfulness of an answer", and if every answer got upvoted by way of "it did not work but still +1 for effort", then votes have no value anymore.

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, it happens too often

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks sir I understand its true if I give upvotes without any reason then votes have no value

Comment: I wish all people that ask questions are like you

Comment: @PeterHaddad why ?

Comment: because sometimes you answer a question, saving OP from spending hours trying to figure it out. Then instead of upvoting your answer and marking it as correct, either he says "thank you" or does not answer anymore lol @viper

Comment: well I understand peter thanks

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Generally, upvotes are yours to do with as you please, except:

1. If you target a user with upvotes, i.e. Upvote every post of theirs you come across regardless of merit, or go through their profile and upvote all of their posts there.
2. If you make a second account to upvote yourself.

Aside from those cases, there aren't strict, enforceable rules for what to upvote.

The *guideline* is to upvote good, clear, helpful posts. From the sounds of it, the answers on your question meet this criteria, so definitely feel free to upvote them!

Upvotes and downvotes are our main quality control metric. So if you find the quality of a post to be good and in line with our standards, go for it. Your vote is anonymous anyway.

A good way to remember this:
If you vote on the *post* based solely on quality and only when you organically/naturally come across them, without regard for who posted it, you'll be fine. If you vote on the *person* posting, you're running down a bad path.

Comment: so it is bad if I target a specific user to upvote

Comment: Yes. In fact, we have systems to catch this. Now if that user posted multiple answers to your post and all of them happen to be good, that's a different matter. But if you try to thank them by upvoting all of their posts, that'll just get reversed by the system, and could even get you a suspension.

Comment: one more thing sir suppose if a same user give answers to my questions and if they are correct and I mark them correct, so is there be a problem if I mark all the answer right to the same user

Comment: If you mean marking answers by the same user with the checkmark on different questions, no issues there so long as it's not two accounts run by the same person. (People do try that...) In some smaller tags, that can actually happen a lot! If you mean upvoting... It's a matter of how natural the votes are. If they're correctly answering your questions and you upvote that answer _as it happens_ and don't specifically hunt it out... That's also acceptable.

Comment: @viper Simply vote on the answers you come across without considering who wrote them, only their quality.  If you do that, there's basically no chance at all that the votes will be deemed fraudulent.

Comment: thanks for the answer to every senior I understand now I just give the upvote if they are right

Comment: @Servy it's a pity that you can't browse a user's catalog and vote as your conscience dictates (without fear of reversal).

Comment: @canon I know what you mean, but it's *extremely* hard to be objective when you immerse yourself in a single user's posts.

Comment: @PM2Ring Objectively, I find that assertion extremely subjective.

Comment: @canon Well played! :)

Comment: I follow several users and upvote most of what they ask or answer, but only if it is good – and it usually is. It would be a shame if that got flagged as I believe it is appropriate.

Comment: @Servy and kendr  upvote on comments with same two accounts continuously will also go to the circumstances of suspension???... Please confirm

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Honestly can't tell you on that one. I mean, comment upvotes are basically meaningless, so... Maybe not? I think that'd be a question to post to all of meta, rather than in the comments here. I don't know how the mods would handle that if they came across it.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, refrain from voting. Definitely don't upvote just because someone made the effort to type something in the answer box.

If you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001818/how-to-connect-socket-in-swift-4), there's three answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002185/: this answer, which you accepted, tells you what to do, but not why (apart from *"make a strong reference"* which seems plausible at best) or why that would solve your problem. I wouldn't upvote.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002320/: "Try this: [code block]". [Not a good answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain/298811#298811), definitely don't upvote.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002286/: that's a comment asking for clarification ("Is X the case? Then do Y"). That's not an answer, but should be a comment. Definitely don't upvote.

As a side note, as you did under the answer you accepted, don't go [ask new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001818/how-to-connect-socket-in-swift-4/50002185#comment87022696_50002185) in comments under an answer.

Comment: You are a bit hard-ass about it.  Keep in mind that he's in the role of the OP and will actually pursue the suggestions.  Unlike a random by-passer.  If they turn out to be accurate/helpful then an upvote is not wrong.  Ideally with a comment that states that the answer was in fact correct so the poster can tweak it.

Comment: thanks for explaining Sir I remember these things in future, for newbies like me its hard to understand the things going on SO

Comment: Sure, you don't have to.  It is the OP's prerogative.  The vast majority of them often already aware that the question is too vague to empower 100% correct answers on the first try.  Such is life in the stacks.  Fwiw, I personally find answers that give no indication at all that the post is based on some amount of guessing a lot worse.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I think you mean "I'll never *back* down on my ... stance".  The phrase "double down" means to take an even stronger position, as in doubling your bet on something in a gambling game.  In this case, doubling down on that position might be to advocate *downvoting*, rather than just not-upvoting.

Comment: While perhaps not broadly answering the question, this answer does analyse the answers to the original SO question in a way in which I completely agree. I see no "hard-assing" here. Voting using your actual brain is crucial to the quality of the site.