# Some questions sneak under the radar?

Tags: discussion, flags, asking-questions

Genuinely interested, why does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850280/i-want-to-create-a-toggle-button-like-this) question not get flagged and closed, but instead up-voted and answered? Let alone the fact that there are several [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+css+toggle+button) on this specific topic, the question is basically saying "hey somebody please write this code for me", and that's exactly what happens. The answer is good enough, and has received a number of up-votes, but I don't understand why the question wasn't closed.

I'm asking in part because I have lost access to the review queues multiple times for what are deemed as incorrect reviews. I'm trying to understand; just curious.

Comment: Basically: because it's a html/css question. Even if it shouldn't happen, voting and flagging works differently depending on the tags that the question is linked to. I don't like to say it but Stack Overflow does know "communities" that operate differently from each other. Some differences are to be expected though. CSS questions for example often are answered with only code. While that is an indicator of a low quality answer for most types of programming questions, when it comes to CSS problems the produced css snippet is generally "nuff said".

Comment: Upvote are personal and we will have to admit that we can't understand all of them.  Sometimes answerer ping the original poster using upvote. So Op can use the answer upvote button to show he has read the answer.

Comment: @Gimby Fair, and I agree to an extent, but this case does not display a problem of any kind, or ask for any sort of solution. It just says can somebody please make this cool thing? If I posted a question asking for someone to "write a script for me that does this" (link), it would get closed and I would get laughed at

Comment: I would expect this issue to have a canonical question by now. The site has grown to the point that we cannot evaluate every single incoming question, and the effect is more noticeable in certain tags.

Comment: @ATomCalledStu yup. For most types of programming questions an indicator that it is a low quality question, for a CSS (or more generic: markup) question however...

Comment: The question title is super duper important.  That question has one that is silver and garlic to most any user that has been around for a while.  The locale of the user helps as well, lots of very enthusiastic voters there.

Comment: @Gimby Yeah, I've found the front-end web side of SO to generally be a lot more tolerant of bad questions - there tends to be a "fastest gun in the west" type approach to upvote and answer even the worst. The only way to get consistently downvoted is to say "no jquery" ;)

Comment: I don't really understand the link between that particular question not being closed (fast enough) and you failing review audits.

Comment: There's really no sneaking about it. The questions (and their answerers) are quite brazen about their disregard of SO's quality standards. There are quite a few high-rep (100+k) users in JavaScript, for example, that continuously answer duplicates. When called out on it, they say, "it's easier to answer than close".

Comment: @AndréKool I’m just trying to better understand what is acceptable and what is not, what requires editing and what is unsalvageable, so I can be better. The link is just in evaluating the quality of all questions.

Comment: Well its gone now

Answer (score 39):

> hey somebody please write this code for me

Oh, you mean any question in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and so on?

Yeah, that's a culture problem.

Why even do the effort of searching (and thereby learning to craft a proper problem statement, because if your search engine understands you, so will a colleague or peer) if you can post a question where you show no effort whatsoever, but just dump your requirements, and get an answer within minutes even though it's the umpteenth incantation of the same question?

The problem lies with the answerers as well. A user with nearly 9K of reputation posting [*"Try this [code block]"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/) to an obvious duplicate is part of the problem. A newly joined user posting a massive code block and claiming it to be a "perfect solution" also is.

Not to sound like a defeatist or anything, but you'd better just ignore such tags. Alternatively, downvote and close-vote where appropriate.

[image: mypart.jpeg]

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose I’m just discouraged by continually being banned from review queues for improper reviews. I’m trying to do my part...

Comment: @ATomCalledStu you will start to recognize the audits at some point, please don't despair.

Comment: Or just use the tag filter in the review queue. Then audits are *really* obvious, since they ignore the filter.

Comment: you can add `python` and `java` to your tag list.

Comment: The code it for me stuff is far too prevalent for my liking in the c# area too, and I stopped doing the reviews, because like @ATomCalledStu I missed some reviews and one I challenged I got quite a lot of crap for (well at least thats how it felt) and yet TBH it was in better shape than half the questions I see... so I said good, audit said bad.. I pretty much got told dont do reviews because Im dyslexic and my grammar is less than perfect..

Comment: I just did some more, got an audit which had wrong flags, it was speculation.. and so i said close.. audit said wrong.. interestingly on the "you got it wrong" they changed the flags as to which languages were relevant.. no, its not like that doesnt matter..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah literally any question in any tag about debugging code is technically asking other people to write code for them.